# UIActivityViewController WhatsApp back to chats button not working

Tags: ios, swift2, ios9

I am presenting a UIActivityViewController to share a url via WhatsApp.
Everything works fine except that the back button in the share dialog of whats app is not working. Swipe to navigate back is working.

Have a look at the screenshot to see the button I am talking about.
[image]

My code to present the activity view controller is:

```
let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com")!
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [url], applicationActivities: nil)
self.videoPlayerController?.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the problem.

Somewhere in my app I configured navigation bar to use a custom back button image in the navigation globally by like this:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorImage = UIImage(named: "back_icon")
UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = UIImage(named: "back_icon")
```

After I changed it to be not globally anymore it worked:

```
self.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = UIImage(named: "back_icon")
self.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = UIImage(named: "back_icon")
```

Thank you stack overflow.